# Java JButton release action

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am new to java and I'm having some problems with Jbuttons. I'm thinking of playing a button click sound when the button is pressed and playing a different sound when the button is released. I already know how to assign an actionlistener to a jbutton, but I have no idea of how to do this, and I didn't find an answer in Google. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to use a `MouseEventListener` and see if the `mousePressed` is on the button and if `mouseRelease` is on the button and play the sounds accordingly.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get when a button is pressed/released. When you add the actionlistner i would first call the sound that it is suppose to make when pressed then have it play the sound it is released at the end of the action listener code.

Comment: I have the feeling combining a ChangeListener with calling button.isSelected() might do the trick. You could maybe give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @Quillion and Ray for your helpful answers. Both your methods work fine.