# Mouse Listener implementation

Tags: java, jbutton, mouselistener

I am learning Java and trying to implement a MouseListener for the first time. I have read the java doc
[MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) but my code doesnt work, as in nothing happens when i press the button.  Here is a jbutton with a pressed and released event.  Can someone explain where i have gone wrong?

```
JButton upButton_1 = new JButton("Up");
    upButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent pevt) {
            upButtonPressPerformed(pevt);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent revt) {
            upButtonReleasePerformed(revt);
        }

        public synchronized void upButtonPressPerformed(
                MouseEvent pevt) {
            resultsTextArea.setText("Up Button Activated, String: " + downString);


                try{
                    //See Above comments for sending ASCII String
                    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(upString);


                    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                            twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

                sw.out.write(bytes);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public synchronized void upButtonReleasePerformed(
        MouseEvent revt) {
        resultsTextArea.setText("Up Button released, String: " + downString);


            try{
                //See Above comments for sending ASCII String
                byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(upString);


                TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

            sw.out.write(bytes);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: a) Explain what you mean by "doesn't work". b) A MouseListener in a JButton? I don't know if there is a reason it won't work, but it doesn't make a lot of sense. I'd try it on something else (like just a JPanel or JLabel) first.

Comment: I want to send a string when the button is pressed and then another string when it is released. At the moment when i press the button nothing happens at all.

Comment: What would you recommend as an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionListener is what you are looking for if you want to work with buttons.

```
JButton button = new JButton("SomeButton");
button.addActionListener(this);

void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button) {
        // do whatever you want if button is clicked
    }
}
```

Or you can use anonymous inner class:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {          
        //do whatever you want
    } 
});

//or the Java8 version
button.addActionListener((e) -> {
    //do whatever you want
});
```

Whit MouseListener you can listen to events like:
MouseClicked, MouseEntered, MouseExited, MousePresse, MouseReleased. 
You could use these, but for button click its more logical to listen to your buttons not your mouse.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.  Actually this is what i had before. Is it possible to have the button press and button release behave differently though? like MousePress and Mouse Release?

Comment: @Display Name "I have the feeling combining a ChangeListener with calling button.isSelected() might do the trick. You could maybe give it a try." This is what I can give you hope it helps. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942131/java-jbutton-release-action

Comment: Actually i think i understand. Thanks!